# Disable tracking pixel download (px file) in my website?

Tags: javascript, html, ads, adsense, tracking-pixel

I have a website that has some advertising (AdSense + MGID) networks. Ocasionally, when visiting the website, it automatically downloads a px file, also known as "tracking pixel".

Is there a way I could disable this download? That is, disabling it without changing anything related to my ad networks and also not having the need of configure anything on the user side.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for modern browsers, you can break tracking pixel loading by CSP rules - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP

But it will probably break advertisement networks, or they will deliver your cheaper advertisements, since your site will display loss of visitors - no pixel loaded makes advertisement network think there is less visitors on your site